# Returning Just Time (in Military) from DB in ASP.NET/VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date, time

I'm saving military time into the database. Then I need to pull this data back out of the database. To get just the time without the date I can do this:

```
String.Format("{0:T}", pullsaved.First.timeValue)
```

But this returns a six digit time, e.g. 100000 (HHmmss). But I want it to return just HHmm (1000). I tried the following, but it didn't work...any ideas?

```
DateTime.ParseExact(String.Format("{0:T}", pullsaved.First.timeValue), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:HHmm}", pullsaved.First.timeValue)
```

or

```
pullsaved.First.timeValue.ToString("HHmm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is:

```
DateTime dt = someDate;
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("HHmm");
```